# How to write a trigger that executes stored procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, ssms

I have a stored procedure that calculates age of the person. Here it is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateAge]
AS
    UPDATE Person
    SET Age = DATEDIFF(year, BirthDate,  GETDATE() ) 
    WHERE Age IS Null;
```

I want to write a trigger which would automatically fill the column age whenever new person is added
Is it possible to write a trigger which would execute the procedure written above or it is easier to write the logic of the procedure in a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution here is not to use a trigger, simply add a computed column to your table

```
alter table MyTable add Age=Datediff(year, BirthDate,  Getdate())
```

This way the value is always correct when you query the table.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table) for full details on computed columns.

Edit

To implement using a trigger for such a simple update it would make sense to do it in the trigger

```
create trigger [dbo].[TriggerName] on dbo.TableName 
for insert 
as
if @@RowCount=0 return
set nocount on

update p set p.age=DateDiff(year, BirthDate, GetDate()) 
from inserted i
     join person p on p.Id = i.Id --<< Id is the primary key of the table
```

Comment: I would stick with a view, that way you have options

Comment: Creating a separate view would imply having to modify code to select from or join to the view, how is that a better option?

Comment: Thank you! It is just that in my work I need to use a trigger

Comment: @jamesss ok in which case I would implement in the trigger, have amended with an example. One other point - `person` singular indicates the table would contain a single person, a better name would be `people` as no doubt you have many.

Comment: No problem, it answers your question but the computed column is still the better solution. By storing an age, it's immediately out of date; what happens when you select the age in the future, it will always be "now" and forever incorrect.

Comment: @Stu In this particular case I would not say better but in a general case I prefer to keep my tables raw and any abstractions of the data to a view. Although since all rows are being modified on update anyways computed column idea holds water

Answer (score 0):

To use a procedure effectively inside a trigger you will want to pass in an argument, for that we can use a user defined table. Although based on question your procedure appears to just update all rows so no argument is necessary.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Person_Update ON dbo.Person AFTER UPDATE
AS
   EXEC dbo.CalculateAge
```

Comment: That is how you execute a procedure, not how you would execute one correctly in the context of a trigger in a set-based fashion; how would your simple exec cope when 2 or 2000 rows are updated.

Comment: pass in user defined table type based on Inserted table

Comment: Great, so add that to your answer!

Comment: @ZachHutchins can you,please, specify what you mean? Don't quite get what do you mean

Comment: @jamesss Yeah showed how it would look inside a trigger creation.. not sure if you are doing it after update just assumed